# Transporting unfermented wort

Tags: wort, transport

I want to brew with some friends in my country house but temperature this time of year there is not ideal to leave the fermentor there so i will have to transport it for about 100 km.I am not sure how to transport the wort after we finish. Should i chill ,transfer to bucket and pitch or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would get the wort into the fermenter with the yeast and then carefully transport it.  Then you don't have to worry about the wort getting contaminated as much due to the airlock on the fermenter.  The head space should be able to handle the sloshing from moving it (I am assuming that this is in a car).  I would just make sure that it isn't going to go sliding around during the transport.

Comment: I noticed a lot of people at the last Big Brew using those plastic milk crates to transfer glass carboys (there empty and back with inoculated wort).